# How to set binding path explicitly?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a wpf desktop app. I am using the datagrid and I populate my grid using a view-model architecture.

I also have a button for each row. I have bound a button (tried) to a command object.

This my MVVM:

```
public class Navigation
{
    private ICommand _ViewJobAction;
    public ICommand ViewJobAction
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                if (_ViewJobAction == null)
                {
                    _ViewJobAction = new MyCommand(
                            param => ViewJob()
                    );
                }
                return _ViewJobAction;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle error
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    private void ViewJob()
    {
       //do some stuff
    }

    private Customers _CustomerRecords;
    public Customers CustomerRecords
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomerRecords;
        }
        set
        {
            _CustomerRecords = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerRecords");
        }
    }
}

public class Customers 
{
    //get data
}
```

In my view:

```
    <DataGrid "{Binding Navigation.CustomerRecords.Records}">
    //defined columns
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
             <Button Command="{Binding Navigation.ViewJobAction ,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Content="View Job">
                        </Button>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This does not invoke my Command in my VM.

In the output window I get this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Navigation' property not found on 'object' ''CustomerRecord' (HashCode=26023080)'. BindingExpression:Path=Navigation.ViewJobAction; DataItem='CustomerRecord' (HashCode=26023080); target element is 'Button' (target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Now I think I understand this error but I do not know how to fix it apart from moving the ViewAction Code to the customer Class which I do not want to do.

My last attempt to get this working was putting the explicit' option in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [RelativeSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) of the binding to point to the `DataGrid`, and then bind to a property of its `DataContext`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ViewJobAction, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
        Content="View Job" />
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, it made sense. :)